# Text collapsing on side menu close

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I prevent text from collapsing on a side menu closing. Check out the codepen and you will see that the menu items/text collapse on top of each other when the menu is closed. I've tried overflow hidden on the menu items but that did not work. Any ideas?

see codepen: https://codepen.io/zepzia/pen/vpZQxz

```
<header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <nav class="navbar bg-faded fixed-top" id="slide-nav">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
              <div class="nav-logo">

                <span class="navbar-text menu-toggle" onclick="openNav()"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
             </div>


              <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
                <br>
                <br>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">This Is Link One</a>
                <a href="#">This Is Link Two</a>
                <a href="#">This Is Link Three</a>
                <a href="#">This IsLink Three</a>
                <a href="#">Link Three</a>
              </div>
       </div>

      </nav>
  </div>
</div>

    </nav>
</header>



    /* NAVIGATION */
.menu-toggle {
cursor:pointer;
float:right;
line-height: 60px;
}

.fa-bars {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
}


.nav-wrapper {
  width: 83%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


.navbar {
  height: 75px;
  background-color: gray;
}



/* The side navigation menu */
.sidenav {
    height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
    width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
    top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
    right: 0;
    background:rgba(75,156,211,0.9) url('../img/unc_pine_cb.svg') no-repeat;
    background-size: 200%;
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
    transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
    padding: 15px 8px 10px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}


/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #13284a;
    font-weight: 600;
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 36px;
}




 /* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px */
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "400px";
}

/* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 */
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}


// FADE OUT ON SCROLL DOWN
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".fade-to-top").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 350);
  });
```

Comment: What if instead of toggling the width you change the right position. so when its closed its right: -400px and when its open right:0. This will add the same effect without the text collapsing. example: https://codepen.io/sunrisem/pen/NXgEex

Comment: @SunriseM was thinking the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to change the `right` attribute instead of the width. So instead you would set the start of the `sidebar` to `right: -400px` and change it to `right: 0px` when the button is clicked. Then reverse when you close the menu.

see my codepen [here](https://codepen.io/codemonkeyco/pen/dJRQQQ)

This way the text will never collapse.